# Need Identical keys in Angular object for payment gateway

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, authorize.net

I am building an application in AngularJS. I need to send transaction data through the Authorize.net gateway:

API Documentation: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/

The only part of the transaction I cannot send is the lineItems which lists the individual items in the purchase. It looks like this:

```
"lineItems": {
    "lineItem": {
        "itemId": "1",
        "name": "Plates",
        "description": "Red Dinnetware Plates",
        "quantity": "18",
        "unitPrice": "45.00"
    },
    "lineItem": {
        "itemId": "2",
        "name": "Cup",
        "description": "Plastic Cups",
        "quantity": "3",
        "unitPrice": "5.00"
    }
},
```

From what I can discern there is not way to have multiple identical keys in an object, unless it is inside an array. Unfortunately the Authorize.net gateway kicks back an error if it sees an array []. I've tried encoding the lineItems as a JSON string (angular.toJson) but when placed in the object it re-encodes the object into Json again during the $http() post and inserts escapes for the quotes rather than the correctly formatted Json.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a good question for Authorize.net support - objects cant have duplicate keys... so not sure what they'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is pretty clear:

```
var lineItem_id1 = new ApiContracts.LineItemType();
lineItem_id1.setItemId('1');
lineItem_id1.setName('vase');
lineItem_id1.setDescription('cannes logo');
lineItem_id1.setQuantity('18');
lineItem_id1.setUnitPrice(45.00);

var lineItem_id2 = new ApiContracts.LineItemType();
lineItem_id2.setItemId('2');
lineItem_id2.setName('vase2');
lineItem_id2.setDescription('cannes logo2');
lineItem_id2.setQuantity('28');
lineItem_id2.setUnitPrice('25.00');

var lineItemList = [];
lineItemList.push(lineItem_id1);
lineItemList.push(lineItem_id2);
```

A `lineItemList` is an array of `lineItem` objects.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else trying to figure out the correct JSON format for Authorize.Net's lineItems, here it is.  I spent hours trying to find examples on the net with no luck.  I finally got it to work by trial and error.

First off, the name element is required, but the description is not.  The item name is limited to 31 characters.  What I did was used a generic name like 'Order Item' and then placed the actual description in the description element. The lineItem element is the acutal array. And now for the format example:

```
"lineItems": {
    "lineItem": [
        {
            "itemId": "1",
            "name": "Plates",
            "description": "Red Dinnetware Plates",
            "quantity": "18",
            "unitPrice": "45.00"
        },
        {
            "itemId": "2",
            "name": "Cup",
            "description": "Plastic Cups",
            "quantity": "3",
            "unitPrice": "5.00"
        }
    ]
},
```